# R Data Types to MonetDB Data Types

Tags: r, monetdb, monetdblite

I am trying to insert a data frame into MonetDB using `DBI::dbWriteTable()` with the `MonetDBLite` driver and am having to adjust column types in both the MonetDB table and the R data frame.

I am wondering if there is a mapping of data types from R to MonetDB. For instance, I know (or assume, rather) a `character` vector in R should map to a MonetDB column of `CHAR(n), CHARACTER(n), VARCHAR(n), CHARACTER VARYING(n), TEXT, CLOB, CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT`, or `STRING` and back.

Is there any official documentation on this? Google isn't turning anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `DBI` function, [`dbDataType`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbDataType), that determines the database type for a R object. The MonetDBLite driver implements this function. For example,

```
> library("DBI")
> con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite())
> dbDataType(con, "asdf")
[1] "STRING"
> dbDataType(con, 1L)
[1] "INTEGER"
> dbDataType(con, 1)
[1] "DOUBLE PRECISION"
```

In case you are interested in the reverse, the R type that is created from a database type, there is also a (private) function in the MonetDBLite driver that does this.

```
> MonetDBLite:::monetdbRtype("BOOLEAN")
  BOOLEAN 
"logical"
```